# Draw line chart in Java using JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx

What i want to do: [image]

How my program looks like:
[image]

So currently i have a table which contains elements. I thought the right idea would be maybe work with lines and circles to draw graph? Or is there a better alternative? Also the main question here is how to set a layout, so if there's an element number one it has a circle under it and if the element is 15 it has an element under it. My thought is for every circle to has it's own row, if one has been placed the next one is 10px below etc. Although still the question remains about layout, any pointers?

E:/

I came up with a little idea to use Line Chart, but the Line Chart doesen't allow me to manipulate it with the way i want. It will just create lines in ascending order but i would like to move from point one to point five and then to point 2 (as shown in the chart above with different elements but the idea is same).

Comment: Your pics are not showing up..

Comment: Edited, now pics are shown.

Comment: I would use a Path build up using LineTo segments ... using the LayoutX of the list objects, layouted above, for X coordinates and calulate the Y coordinate as desired (available space etc.)